# Add FROM docker image build variable in docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image using a variable for my FROM docker base image

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /ionic-app
    environment:
      NODE_VER: 12.16.0
```

Dockerfile

```
# Create Basic docker file 
FROM node:${NODE_VER}
```

But this doesn't work I get, I've read that this isn't possible or that you need to add build arguments for this to work?

```
ERROR: Service 'ionic-app' failed to build: invalid reference format
```

Is this possible? I want to make it so when Node updates their LTS version I'll easily be able to change versions via arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using arguments:

Dockerfile

```
ARG NODE_VER=latest
FROM node:$NODE_VER
...
```

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_VER: "12.16.0"
    working_dir: /ionic-app
```